# How to remove multiple words, Not replace!, from a string Java

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I'm new to java and currently I'm learning strings.

How to remove multiple words from a string? I would be glad for any hint.

The replacement doesn't work as it deletes a part of a word.

```
class WordDeleterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordDeleter wordDeleter = new WordDeleter();

        // Hello
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("Hello Java", new String[] { "Java" }));

        // The Athens in
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("The Athens is in Greece", new String[] { "is", "Greece" }));

        // This cat
        System.out.println(wordDeleter.remove("This is cat", new String[] { "is" }));
    }
}

class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
        String result = phrase;
        for (String word : words) {
            result = result.replace(word, "");
        }
        return result.trim();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
The Athens in
Th cat
```

Comment: `result = result.replaceAll("\\b" + word + "\\b", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class WordDeleter {
    public String remove(String phrase, String[] words) {
        String result = phrase;
        for (String word : words) {
            result = result.replaceAll("\\b" + word + "\\b", "");
        }
        return result.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceAll uses a regex so you do not need a loop. Instead make an `or` regex out of the words array.

```
result = phrase.replaceAll("\\W("+String.join("|", words)+")\\W","");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue, "Th cat"

Comment: I skipped that sentence in the question. The regex can accommodate this requirement, but it could be a little tricky to find all the edge cases. I will update the answer to cover the most common ones.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using replace or replaceAll with regexp

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String originalstring = "This is cat";
        System.out.println ("Original String: " + originalstring);
        System.out.println ("Modified String: " + originalstring.replaceAll("\\s(is)", ""));
    }
```

`\\s(is)` represents that all fragment space + is